# How to correctly return asynchronous query result as Task<IAsyncEnumerable<string>>?

Tags: api, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

I try to return **asynchronous **query result as Task<IAsyncEnumerable>, but can't figure out how to do it correctly. For example everything looks to be ok until I use `await` keyword.

No error:
`

```
public async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<string>> GetUserRoles(User user, int userPermisionsId)
        {
            using (XXX db = new XXX())
            {
                var userRoles =  db.WebAppUserRoles
                .Where(x => x.PermisionsId == userPermisionsId)
                .Include(x => x.WebAppRole)
                .Select(x => new WebAppRole
                {
                    WebAppRoleName = x.WebAppRole.WebAppRoleName
                })
                .Select(x => x.WebAppRoleName)
                .AsAsyncEnumerable();

                return userRoles;
            }
        }
```

`

I get an error (CS1061'IAsyncEnumerable' does not contains a definition for 'GetAwaiter'...)`:

`

```
public async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<string>> GetUserRoles(User user, int userPermisionsId)
        {
            using (XXX db = new XXX())
            {
                var userRoles =  await db.WebAppUserRoles
                .Where(x => x.PermisionsId == userPermisionsId)
                .Include(x => x.WebAppRole)
                .Select(x => new WebAppRole
                {
                    WebAppRoleName = x.WebAppRole.WebAppRoleName
                })
                .Select(x => x.WebAppRoleName)
                .AsAsyncEnumerable();

                return userRoles;
            }
        }
```

`

Is my method still asynchronous even if I don't use await keyword? I'm new in asynchronous programming topic and I'm bit lost in it...

I was looking for an answer on stackoverflow

Comment: If you don't use `await` on an `async` method, the compiler will still build a state machine. So, you're paying all the cost for no benefit. Play with it at https://sharplab.io

Comment: Helpful information, thank you!